# save the nth row of file using script shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Hello im writing a script bash. I want to store the nth row in variable within my script.

**code**
for example for position 2.

```
sed -n '2p' < file.txt
```

Does anyone knows how to do it please?

Comment: use command substitution.  `variable=$(sed -n '2p' < file.txt)`

Comment: Thank you for your response but .my row number is stored in **v=i** . How should I to read it please? I did this but got error variable=$(sed -n '$v' < file.txt)

Comment: Shell variables does not expand in single quotes.

Comment: `row=7; sed -n "${row}p" file.txt`

Comment: @Quasímodo thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

```
variable=$(sed -n '2p' < file.txt|cut -f 7)
```

Or try to split string with awk, is column separator is not tab